# Lines Boxed Out in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, arabic, right-to-left

I'm having some difficulty producing the table of contents for my MA thesis. For reasons I can't figure out, several lives are appearing solely as boxes, and appear to be oriented right-to-left. My thesis uses quite a lot of Arabic, but there's no Arabic text in the section titles. I'm making the TOC with a simple \tableofcontents command.

I'm using a very large number of packages. Those that seem possibly relevant are bidi and polyglossia. I've tried commenting bidi out, but it doesn't fix the problem.

I don't imagine that this is enough information for anyone to tell me what the problem is, but I'm actually a bit stumped as to how to even begin looking for a solution. Has anyone run into a situation similar to this before? Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Try starting at chapter/section 3.5, and back-track into 3.4 to find the last rtl text, and see if an environment or selectlanguage command (depending on how you do things) has been opened but not closed.

Comment: Thanks! I should have been able to figure that out. It turns out that I was using \begin{Arabic}\end{Arabic} in contexts in which I ought to have been using \textarabic{}. The text was produced correctly on the page, but it was apparently mucking up the table of contents as well as some of the page numbering. Once again: Thank you.